# Se espera un nombre de metodo C# Cargar datos SQL

Tags: c#, sql

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection ("Data Source = ACER-E5; Initial Catalog = mantenedorclientes; Integrated Security = True")) 
{
    cn.Open ();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("Select rut,nombre,apellidop,apellidom from clientes where rut ='" + dato + "'");
    SqlDataReader leer = cmd.ExecuteReader ();

    if (leer.Read ()) {
        txt_rut.Text = Convert.ToString (leer ("rut")); //Leer muestra el error "Se espera un nombre de metodo "

    } else { }
    leer.Close ();

}
```

Lo que quiero es tomar esos datos de la consulta e insertarlos en varios textbox.

Comment: Proba cambiar `txt_rut.Text = Convert.ToString(leer("rut"));` por `txt_rut.Text = leer.GetString(1);` o por  `txt_rut.Text = leer["rut"].ToString();`

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal podes poner eso como respuesta? al fin y al cabo es esa la respuesta, mas la explicacion de porque le paso lo que le paso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu problema se da porque estas utilizando tu objeto `leer` como si fuese un método, pero no lo es, es una instancia de la clase `SqlDataReader`.

Se puede ver en la [documentación de microsoft de la clase SqlDataReader](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.7.2) cuales son los métodos y propiedades que expone, para este caso en particular, nos interesa:

**Propiedades**

- [Item[String]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.item?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_Item_System_String_)

**Métodos**

- [GetString(Int32)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetString_System_Int32_)
- [GetInt32(Int32)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetInt32_System_Int32_)

Teniendo en cuenta lo mencionado antes, vamos a tu caso en particular

---

Para aplicar al ejemplo, voy a asumir que la columna `rut`es de tipo `Int32`, y el resto cadenas.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select rut,nombre,apellidop,apellidom from clientes where rut ='"+dato+"'");
SqlDataReader leer = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (leer.Read())
{
    //Obtengo el contenido de la primer columna de la query utilizando el método GetInt32(Int32)
    int rut = leer.GetInt32(0);
    //Obtengo el contenido de la segunda columna de la query utilizando el método GetString(Int32)
    string resultado = leer.GetString(1);
    //Obtengo el contenido de la tercer columna de la query utilizando la propiedad Item[String]
    string nombre = leer["nombre"];
}
```

Por si no quedó claro, el parámetro que se pasa a los métodos `GetString(Int32)` y `GetInt32(Int32)` es la posición (comenzando por cero) de la columna que se pretende obtener dentro de la query